# Can't change world color. Cycles and blender render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, color

Im trying to brighten the world, but it does not change. What is the problem?

Video here: [video](https://youtu.be/k-kRcFTFyIE)

Comment: World color affects your render's background (F12), but I think that what you actually want to change is the `Viewport background color`, which is a setting that you find in the `User preferences`

Comment: I want to change the render color, not the ui

Comment: In your video you are effectively changing your world color, but you're not rendering, so you can't see the result of your change. That's why I thought that you wanted to change the viewport color instead. However, Paul Gonet's answer should be the right one for you: it links the viewport color to the (render) world color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the ***World Background*** checkbox in a Display panel of a properties shelf (<kbd>N</kbd>).
[image]

You may also switch the shading mode from *Solid* to ***Rendered*** to see the result.
[image]